# jenkins htmlpublisher plugin install error

Tags: jenkins-plugins

i wanted to install the HTML Publisher plugin in jenkins but when i try that, getting below error, any suggestion how to get the plugin installed.

jenkins version: 1.630.

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1328)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install htmlpublisher plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:485)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1324)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Dependency workflow-step-api (1.4) doesn't exist
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:480)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:475)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be 2 ways to install a plugin.

1. Download the hpi plugin file and place it in the plugin directory and restart the jenkins.
2. Install the plugin using the plugin section in the jenkins gui.

Looks like you are trying the first method. If so you need to first install the dependency plugins

> workflow-step-api (version:1.4)
>
> matrix-project (version:1.0)

[image]

Check this link for the same: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

If you are trying with second method, jenkins will take care of dependency installation.